# Magento 1: How replacing WYSIWYG button in product description field?

Tags: product, attributes, magento-1, wysiwyg

By default when there is an attribute with "Enable WYSIWYG" set to Yes you will get a button bellow that form field [WYSIWYG Editor]. When you click on the button your will get a pop-up window, but this takes long and it is annoying when you do this task many times.

I would like to replace this button with those 4 buttons which are available when editing a CMS page content, just for Description in product edit page. In this way there is no pop-up window displayed and it is easy to insert static blocks, widgets, variables, in case this content repeats in many places. See the image bellow for what I mean.

[image]